# Differences between local testrpc and Ropsten testnet

Tags: solidity, testrpc, ropsten

I've noticed that smart-contracts will behave differently when deployed on Ropsten vs local testrpc. I was wondering what specifically changes when a contract gets deployed.

Answer (score 1):

One important difference now is that Ropsten has activated the byzantinum fork so it has support for the new opcodes like REVERT. And testrpc does not have support for them [yet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/402).